# How do I solve assertion error in c for cmd?

Tags: c, file, fopen

I am making a `C` program that reads the number of characters in text file (*.txt)

Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("How to use this program: WC FileName\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE* fp = NULL;

    fopen_s(fp, argv[1], "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("data.txt Failed opening this file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int iLine = 0, iWord = 0, iCh = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        iCh++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Character: %d", iCh);

    return 0;
}
```

My error message:

> Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: result != nullptr

Comment: Which file is the `assert` in?  Can you post that?

Comment: `fopen_s(&fp, argv[1], "w");` <- Note the `&`.

Comment: opening `fp` in `w` mode , but you are trying to read from it.

Comment: It must be `int ch`

Comment: It was & problem.. Thank you so much and hope you have a great holiday! Thanks!